# Windows 2003 cluster issue

Tags: windows-server-2003

We used windows 2003 R2 cluster with two nodes. Recently both the servers crashed due to some reasons!

So below was the steps I tried to recover the system:

1. I install the same OS (2003 R2 enterprise) on both server
2. Restore the all data including system status using NTBACKUP tool.

Everything is OK ! After logging in to both system, the cluster services can't be started.

I want to know anything need to pay attention when restoring the cluster node?

Thanks.

Comment: What applictions are running on this cluster?

Comment: Can you please add the errors you are getting from the cluster service in the event log?

Comment: DB2 and SAP A1 Application running on this cluster?

Answer (score 0):

A system state backup is not enough to restore a failover cluster:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786625(v=ws.10).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780320(v=ws.10).aspx

The standard solution would be to evict the failed node from the cluster and then re-add it; but since *both* nodes failed in your case, you'll probably have to destroy the cluster and re-create it from scratch, if you don't have all you need to restore it (see the two articles I linked above).